# How do I append a country to a views exposed filter field geofield proximity?

Tags: views

Using Geofield with Google's API, when a user enters "Vancouver", it assumes I mean "Vancouver, Washington", when I actually want "Vancouver, BC". Is there any way to append "Canada" to the location info submitted to google?

It would be nice if I could do this with some override but will accept a hack to the module and I will just keep track of the modified module.

Here is a link to Geofeild's code that covers this. http://pastebin.com/Diwj5deE

Note: That I just need the country appended to the info sent to google. I don't want the filter to have a default of "Canada" and it can't prefilter the view with "Canada". It is not until the user actually uses the exposed 
filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any form, a custom module can modify the `#submit` array to put a submission handler in front of the views exposed filter form to preprocess the data.

Here we're just modifying the submitted origin value so that " Canada" is appended if any text is entered by the user:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_submit');
}

/**
 * Modify submission value if given origin has been supplied.
 */
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  if (isset($form_state['values']['field_geofield_distance']['origin']) && 
      strlen($form_state['values']['field_geofield_distance']['origin']) > 0) {
    $form_state['values']['field_geofield_distance']['origin'] .= ' Canada';
  }
}
```

Comment: Quick follow up question. Any reason whay I might be seeing this php notice in my logs? It appears to be due to this code. Notice: Undefined index: field_geofield_distance in custom_form_views_exposed_form_submit()

Comment: The example code didn't cover the scenario where `field_geofield_distance` might not be defined. You can add a `isset()` call to the conditional to catch the warning.